# Spring-Kafka: Can I write null to the cache if I have an empty string?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm creating a project in spring-kafka where I insert a message into a repository that I send to it through kafka that populates asql database with the same fields. The message is a simple Json format containing these value strings:

```
{
"firstName":"Mark",
"lastName":"Hardtree",
"age":"26",
"email":"myemail@com"
}
```

I add my Kafka consumer :

```
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic.name}")
    public void listen(@Validated User user) {

        User  user = new User(user);
        UserRepository.save(user.getName(), user);
    }
}
```

I wish I could be sure that in case I have an empty string, a null is written. So far in case you don't specify a field such as

```
"lastName":""
```

In my cache I find the empty string instead of the null. Is it possible to make this change?

Comment: Assuming you are using the `JsonSerializer`, you might need to write a custom Jackson serializer for `User` objects and configure the `JsonSerializer`'s `ObjectMapper` to use it. Refer to the Jackson documentation.

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you so much for your reply and for the work done on spring-kafka! I wanted to ask you is it possible to put the @JsonDeserializer annotation on the entire User class without having to manually put it in the individual fields.it's possible?

Comment: I meant the spring-kafka `JsonSerializer`; I am not a Jackson expert; sorry.